# Есть ли в C# интерфейс предоставляющий доступ к элементу коллекции по индексу без изменения коллекции

Tags: c#

Есть ли в C# интерфейс предоставляющий доступ к элементу коллекции по индексу без изменения коллекции? Мне хочется записать в поле класса хранить коллекцию, как массивов так и списков, а также иметь возможность обращаться к ним по индексу. есть  ли в С# встроенный интрефейс или необходимо использовать IEnumerable и ElementAt?

Comment: `IReadOnlyList<T>`

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, что IReadOnlyList введён с .net 4.5. Также непонятно, чем обычный массив не угодил - там тоже есть доступ по индексу из коробки.